# Pass react router as context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React application where my main component looks like this:

```
    var App = React.createClass({

        childContextTypes:{
            router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
        },

        getChildContext: function() {
            return {router: this.props.router};
        },

        render: function() {
            return (
                <Router history={browserHistory}>
                    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
                        <IndexRoute component={Index} />
                        <Route path={About.path} component={About} />

                        <Redirect from="/auth" to="/auth/login" />
                        <Route path="auth" component={AuthIndex}>
                            <Route path="login" component={LoginComponent}/>
                            <Route path="register" component={RegisterComponent} />
                        </Route>
                    </Route>
                </Router>
            );
        }
    });

module.exports = App;
```

I am trying to reference the router from a subcomponent like this:

```
contextTypes: {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

And this:

```
      var router = this.context.router
      router.push("/");
```

However, on this last line I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

So how can I correctly pass React Router to a subcomponent using context?

Comment: `this` is undefined. I don't think there is any problem with react-router in that case. Why `this` is undefined? Please provide the code where you call it.

Comment: I made a mistake when writing the error message. I updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

In our usage of ReactRouter this works using Es6

```
App.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Comment: So this can be used instead of:
        `childContextTypes:{
            router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
        },

        getChildContext: function() {
            return {router: this.props.router};
        }`

Comment: No I think the router type you are defining is wrong, I think it is of type object, sadly the context documentation is awful in React Router. I had the same issue and solved it setting the way I posted. If you need more info about the context try and look at this article: https://medium.com/@skwee357/the-land-of-undocumented-react-js-the-context-99b3f931ff73#.kngyjr1pk